# Transfer matrix method with inclined boundaries

Tags: optics, interference

[image]It is straightforward to numerically compute complex reflectivity ($r$) and transmission ($t$) of a layered structure with parallel boundaries by transfer matrix method (TMM). Now, if we have a structure with an inclined layer (see the picture below) $r(x)$ and $t(x)$ become spatially dependent due to the interference pattern between multiple reflections from the boundaries. One can implement TMM simulation pixel-by-pixel in x direction (e.g., pix1 and pix2 have different layer thciknesses but parallel boundaries). However, I am afraid it is too slow to loop over all the pixel and I don't really get how can I account for spatial dependence in transfer matrixes $M$. Could somebody come up with a more efficient method?

Comment: For that structure you lay out the transfer matrix by hand and see the dependence on the thickness of the n_2 layer...

Comment: @JonCuster, thanks for the comment! Did I got you wrong? : let's say I have 500 pixels in x-axis and $L(x)$ dependence of the thickness of n_2 layer. Then I start TMM pixel-by-pixel in 500 iterations: x=1: $M_{1}*M_{2}(x=1)*M_{3} , $x=2: $M_{1}*M_{2}(x=2)*M_{3}$...where $M_{1}, M_{2}$ and $M_{3}$ are the matrixes for the 1st,2nd and 3rd layers?